# How do I expand this to a power series?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am given the function

$$f(x) = \dfrac{6x^2}{(16+2x^3)^2}$$

I am stuck trying to expand $f(x)$ to a power series with center of $0$. I cannot seem to figure how to get $f(x)$ to a clean geometric series form or manipulate it and am confused how to go about it. Thanks!

Image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PX5g.png)

Comment: HINT:  What is $\int f(x)\,dx$?  SECOND HINT:  Geometric Series.

Answer (score 2):

A Maclaurin series is given by

$$f\left(x\right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}\left(a\right)}{k!}x^k$$

In our case we have:
$$f\left(x\right) \approx P\left(x\right) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{5}\frac{f^{(k)}\left(a\right)}{k!}x^k$$

I stop me for $n=5$. You can calculate the derivates and you will have

$$f\left(x\right)\approx\frac{0}{0!}x^{0}+\frac{0}{1!}x^{1}+\frac{\frac{3}{64}}{2!}x^{2}+\frac{0}{3!}x^{3}+\frac{0}{4!}x^{4}+\frac{- \frac{45}{64}}{5!}x^{5}\iff P\left(x\right) = \frac{3}{128}x^{2}- \frac{3}{512}x^{5}$$

At the end:

$$\frac{6 x^{2}}{\left(2 x^{3} + 16\right)^{2}}\approx P\left(x\right)=\frac{3}{128}x^{2}- \frac{3}{512}x^{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of @Mark Viola 's hint, we can rewrite as
$$f(x)=\frac{6x^2}{16^2}\cdot \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{-x^3}{8}\right)^2}=\frac{3x^2}{128}\cdot g\left(-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^3\right)$$
Where of course
$$g(t):=\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}$$
Notice that
$$g(t)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left\{\frac{1}{1-t}\right\}$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Hi and excuse me....But I have not understood the question then?

Comment: @Sebastiano Your work appears to be correct so far. You're just missing the fact that there is a nice closed formula for the coefficients of expansion.

Comment: I have undestood only that the user want the expansion of the function. Often I wrong to understand the questions. My +1.